# Jquery & prototype error

Tags: jquery

Im trying to use colorbox coupled with apimenu with a prototype script. The api menu & colorbox load correctly but the prototype script ceases to load.

Url for colorbox / apimenu below. Please click the regional & more to see colorbox. Is there a way i can resolve this confict? i have used jquery noconflict but seems like Im missing something.. Please help

http://hexaedge.com/menu/

I'm using the below script on index.html & the colorbox $ has been replaced to jquery, but when i changed the men.js $ to jquery, the highlights disappear

```
<script>
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict(true);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use self-invoking anyonymouse function which would allow you to use `$` without conflict:

```
(function($){
  // you can now use $ here
  // your jQuery related code here...
})(jQuery)
```